# How to call a make dependency after the others

Tags: build, makefile, dependencies

For example:

```
build: ...
        do some building

clean:
        do some cleaning

build_and_clean: build clean
```

In `build_and_clean`, how can I make sure `clean` runs after `build`? Is there another way to call `clean` other than as a dependency? I want to avoid doing a recursive call to `make`, and I also want to avoid repeating the code in the `clean` rule.

Comment: That's okay, due to make build_and_clean, make will make build and then make clean.

Comment: Umm... I think you mean *clean then build*.

Comment: @laune the order of dependencies is unspecified

Comment: @Beta, no I mean build and then clean all intermediate files, but that's irrelevant since a solution to one solves the other as well

Comment: Make has ways of removing intermediate files, but for the general problem I can't think of anything more elegant than defining a sequence of commands for cleaning, to be used by `clean` and `build_and_clean`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it. You could use double colon rules:

```
build: ...
        do some building

clean:
        do some cleaning

build_and_clean:: build 
build_and_clean:: clean
```

The [documentation states](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Double_002dColon.html)

> The double-colon rules for a target are executed in the order they appear in the makefile. However, the cases where double-colon rules really make sense are those where the order of executing the recipes would not matter.

Generally speaking I agree with what they say there since it is very often the case in complex builds that double colon rules for a single target are going to be assembled from a variety of sources and the order in which these sources are parsed may not be guaranteed. However, in the case at hand here we know where all the rules come from. And make is not at liberty to reorder them.

This would also do it without having to substantially repeat code. I've use `echo` commands to simulate the execution of build commands:

```
define CLEAN
echo clean
endef

build:
    echo build

clean:
    $(call CLEAN)

build_and_clean: build
    $(call CLEAN)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer one of the solutions you want to avoid myself, but as an alternative
there's this rather laboured sort of thing:

```
.PHONY: any build clean build_and_clean

any:
    @if [ ! -z "$(dobuild)" ]; \
    then \
        echo "doing some building"; \
    fi
    @if [ ! -z "$(doclean)" ]; \
    then \
        echo "doing some cleaning"; \
    fi

build: dobuild = 1
build: any

clean: doclean = 1
clean: any

build_and_clean: dobuild = 1
build_and_clean: doclean = 1
build_and_clean: any
```